# Is the Wordpress REST API installed and enabled in a vanilla Wordpress 4.7 installation?

Tags: rest-api

I've just installed Wordpress 4.7.  One of the mentions in the announcement is that it features a REST API.

My understanding is:

- The Wordpress REST API plugin is not needed anymore, because supposely it has already been merged with core in Wordpress 4.7.
- The Wordpress REST API is enabled by default

However, I notice that in a vanilla Wordpress 4.7 install, none of the endpoints seems to work (for example `http://examples.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`).

How can I tell if the new REST API is really activated?  Can the REST API be enabled or disabled with the vanilla Wordpress UI, or should I install a third party plugin to do so?

Comment: Is there discovery tag in page source? `<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='https://example.com/wp-json/' />` Seems to just work on my sites.

Comment: @Rarst, if I `grep -r "<link rel='https://api.w.org/'" .` in the `html`directory, it returns one hit in file `./wp-includes/rest-api.php` with this text: `echo "<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='" . esc_url( $api_root ) . "' />\n";`

Comment: Not in your _source_ code, in the HTML source of a page from your site in browser.

Comment: @Rarst, yes I see `<link href="http://example.com/wp-json/" rel="https://api.w.org/">`

Comment: What does opening the link in browser get you? With WP_DEBUG enabled?

Comment: I get a 404 for `http://example.com/wp-json/` both with `WP_DEBUG` set as `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

4.7 has it enabled by default. The easy way to check if it is working is just to visit the example.com/wp-json url, and you should get a list of registered end points there

There is no official option to disable it as (at least there was a talk about it not sure if it got in the release), some core functionality depends on it.

The most obvious things to check for if it is not working is your htaccess rules, and do you have a wp-json directory

Also, if `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` type URLs don't work for you, but `/?rest_route=/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` does, it means you need to enable pretty permalinks in the settings (suggested by Giles Butler in comments below).

Comment: I do not have a wp-json directory under `/var/www/html` or its subdirectories.  I do not seem to have a `.htaccess` file (other than `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess`, should I have one?

Comment: @Pep, what webserver do you use? do you have pretty permalinks on?

Comment: Apache.  I followed exactly the steps in these tutorials to install Wordpress 4.7 on AWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

Comment: not familiar with AWS but if you installed a vanilla wordpress you should have had an .htaccess at the root of your install. If not try to go to setting > permalinks, make sure you are not on the plain setting, save, and then check if an htaccess was generated

Comment: I had the permalink with the "Plain" settings. I changed it to "Post name".  Wordpress could not save the .htaccess file apparently because of permissions, so it gave me the code. I created a `.htaccess` file using `ssh` with that content.  However, the REST API continues to return 404, even for  http:example.com/wp-json/

Comment: should not get 404. check if any other pretty url work, like the default post. If it doesn't then you still have an htaccess problem

Comment: It seems that Permalink does work at all, not only the API endpoints.  I just ntoced that I only can access to bot posts with "Plain", if I change Permalinks to any other value, I get the warning that I should change the `.htaccess` file manually, which I do, but then I get 404 even for blog posts.  So I think that my issue is with Permalink al large, rather than with the REST API only.  Perhaps that ".htaccess file not writeable"  is a symtom of some other issue.

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite installed and activated?

Comment: I found finally the issue.  Because I did not know that Permalink would be required for the REST API to work, I skipped during initial setup the step to set `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">`section of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.  That's why it was ignoring my changes to `.htaccess`.  Now with a permalink other than PLain, the REST API endpoints work.

Comment: If you’re using non-pretty permalinks, you should pass the REST API route as a query string parameter. The route http://oursite.com/wp-json/ in the example above would hence be http://oursite.com/?rest_route=/  "https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/#routes-endpoints"

Answer (score 13):

I had 4.7 also thought that REST API was disabled, but I was tricked by the URL. To see the correct URL seek a line looking something like that:

link rel='`https://api.w.org/`' href='`http://mysite?rest_route=/`' />. 
So, using http://mysite?rest_route=/ as the prefix solved my problem. For instance to recover the posts is enought to type: http://mysite?rest_route=/wp/json

I couldn't find on documentation that the query param was needed. Was I the only one?

Comment: Worked for me with wordpress 4.8.x Not sure why this is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Not the only one. Only found this answer in your comment after 10min searching. Needed to do: `www.example.com?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts`

Comment: I think this happens when pretty permalinks aren't enabled. From the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints)...

"On sites without pretty permalinks, the route is instead added to the URL as the rest_route parameter. For the above example, the full URL would then be http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/123"

Comment: here it is -> https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/#routes-endpoints

Comment: Very useful if you are testing out using PHP builtin sever `php -S localhost:1234`.

Answer (score 7):

If REST API isn't working out-of-box or after a fresh install and after typing in

```
mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

then you would need to simply activate your "permalinks" as post_name located:

WP Dashboard->Settings->Permalinks

Or if you do not wish to activate permalinks, you can simply type:

```
mydomain?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts
```

Man, I wish WordPress would update their Rest handbook to be more user-friendly. I like the old version of docs :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you have fixed the issue but leaving my solution here as it worked for me too. I had this same issue when updating from beta15 to the core api in wp 4.7 Turns out the issue was that I had some plugins that were using a deprecated function register_api_field which I changed to register_rest_field according to this note in the changelog:

> BREAKING CHANGE: Rename register_api_field() to register_rest_field().
>
> Introduces a register_api_field() function for backwards compat, which
>   calls _doing_it_wrong(). However, register_api_field() won't ever be
>   committed to WordPress core, so you should update your function calls.